# Opposite of getJSON()?

Tags: json, send

I have a survey web app, and currently I'm grabbing data from a site using this method:

```
$.getJSON("http://quicksurvey.herokuapp.com/api/surveys/:token/ask.json",function(result){...}
```

Where :token is a varying piece of data sent from that url that I grab.

Now then, I need to do something similar.... but opposite. I'd like to send json data to a certain URL, namely this one:

```
http://quicksurvey.herokuapp.com/questions/:token/answer.json?value=:value
```

Where :token and :value I will just swap out with values from my page. So basically, whatever that first url (quicksurvey.herokuapp.com/api) is doing to send me data, I need to do that in my app.

Comment: .getjson isn't anything special. it's just a .get where the returned data is assumed to be in JSON format. to send json, you don't do anything other than a normal `$.get()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to print your JSON and escape it so that you can add it to a URL.